# Always keep a widget on top of the others in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, topmost

Is there any way to always keep a widget on top of the others in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button_1 = Button(root , text = "Button 1")
button_1.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

button_2 = Button(root , text = "Button 2")
button_2.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

mainloop()
```

Here, I positioned `button_1` and `button_2` in the same row, but the problem is that, as I defined `button_2` after defining `button_1`, `button_2` stays on top of `button_1`.

What I want is that `button_1` should always be on top of the other widgets in the window.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: write button_1 after button_2

Comment: if you always want to keep one button on top then why define another button

Comment: @vanditvasa: This was just an example to demonstrate my problem. My actual code is different.

Comment: @vanditvasa as I said write that widget last then

Comment: @Matiiss: Well, What I want to define new widgets in the future?

Comment: ok, but why would You place them on top then? just put the new widgets somewhere else

Comment: use `button_1.lift()` at the end

Comment: @Matiiss by that method you would be hardcoding it. nad hardcoding is not a good practice in programing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.lift()`

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button_1 = Button(root , text = "Button 1")
button_1.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

button_2 = Button(root , text = "Button 2")
button_2.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

button_1.lift()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! The `.lift()` method works, but it should be added at the last after defining `button_2`.

Comment: Just as a note to anyone looking at this in the future: `.lift` doesn't work for `tk.Canvas` widgets. For `tk.Canvas` use `<tk.Canvas>.tk.call("raise", <tk.Canvas>._w, None)`

Comment: @Lenovo360 Yes it has to be obviously defined after defining all the widgets.

Comment: @TheLizzard for `tk.Canvas` we can use `canvas.tag_raise(widget)`

Comment: @vanditvasa I think you misunderstood me. I was saying that if you want raise a canvas that is in a frame/window you can't use `.lift()` because you get a `_tkinter.TclError` error (`.tag_raise` also gives the same error).

Comment: @TheLizzard I am sorry as I am not aware of the current syntax bcoz the last time I used it was 4 years back, and it worked perfectly fine back then.

Comment: @vanditvasa: `tag_raise` works _for canvas items_, not widgets. For the canvas itself, to lift the canvas above other widgets, you must use the `lift` method. However, there's a bug in tkinter where `canvas.lift` calls `canvas.tag_raise`. So, if you want to actually call `lift` on the canvas itself, you have to use a workaround.